# Jedis - Redis : Does maximum number of clients increases chances of response time from Redis?

Tags: java, redis, apache-commons, jedis

We are using jedis to connect to redis. We are looking for some insights to configure jedispool. So far our configuration for pool is as below

```
TIMEOUT=1000
MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS=1500
MAX_IDLE=800
MIN_IDLE=500
MAX_WAIT_TIME_MILLIS=1000
TEST_ON_BORROW=false
TEST_ON_RETURN=false
TEST_WHILE_IDLE=false
```

Server throughput is ~200 requests per second and ~50 redis hits per requests.

My question is, if I increase number of connected clients, will it help. Or how to configure this connection pool. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely not. In fact it will only slow things down, since you're allowing more connections to be made, but you don't have any more resources to handle those connections.

Comment: What do you mean by 'any more resources'?

Comment: The server doesn't get any more powerful even if you're allowing more simultaneous connections.

Comment: Let's view it from a different angle: Redis is single-threaded. More connections result in more overhead but won't improve application performance. Other clients like [lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) or [redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) allow connection sharing by multiple application threads that naturally fits Redis' nature.